# Django Celery : Something wrong with shared_task

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery

I use django-rest-framework and celery
this ims my views.py

```
# GET /server/test/<para>/                                               
class Testcelery(APIView):
    def test(self):
        print(celery_test())

    def get(self, request, para, format=None):
        print('test')
        self.test()
        # result = add.delay(4, 4)
        # print(result.id)
        result = OrderedDict()
        result['result'] = 'taskid'
        result['code'] = status.HTTP_200_OK
        result['message'] = 'success'
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

this is a simple celery task

```
@shared_task()                                                             
def celery_test():
    print('celerytest')
    return True
```

I debug the django
[it can goes to the test method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVLHs.png)

but the program stuck at the next step in **call** in local.py
[where the error happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3JTI.png)

the debug stops there, and shows like this
[debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyOus.png)

Comment: There could be a few things. 1) Do you have the celery worker running?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

Tasks are supposed to run with `whatever.delay()` http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#basics

I wouldn't call a class `Testsomething` unless it's a test class

Make sure the worker is running and that it is initialized correctly. Don't forget to check if the broker is running correctly.

When debugging, take into account that the celery worker is a different process. Your debugger is probably attached only to the process running manage.py. If you run the worker as a command from the IDE, it'll probably be easier to debug.